# Как удалить тень у элементов?

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать тень с элементов формы. Раньше у них не было тени, а аккуратненькая рамочка, но потом что-то случилось и теперь все элементы на форме окружают максимально некрасивые тени. И такое абсолютно у всех элементов, даже у QMessageBox.
Вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше было вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я подозреваю, что речь идет о релизной версии программы, а не той, которая запускается из среды?

Comment: Ой, спасибо огромное. Поменял режим сборки с релиза на дебаг и все стало хорошо